# Items length in Windows 10 Start screen

Tags: windows-10, start-screen

I use Windows 10 (Enterprise, Version 1709, OS Build 16299.125).

The evolution of Start menu/screen since Win8 ended up in something very weird for me. I don't care much if it is full screen or what but I need to quickly find what I want and get idea what's there at a glance by scrolling the view. So it drives me crazy what I see in the current system, especially for SQL Server menu groups: [image: screenshot]

Why the rows are so narrow when there is lots of empty space around? There are multiple versions of SQL Server and to figure out which entry is which you have to point the mouse cursor and wait for the popup!!!

Is there any setting I could use to get wider columns in Start screen?

Comment: Windows 10 Start Menu is full screen only while in tablet mode.  “Why the rows are so narrow when there is lots of empty space around?“ You have not placed tiles there yet but you are also using Tablet Mode at a resolution that it really wasn’t designed for.

Comment: @Ramhound it is not in tablet mode. I switched on setting Personalization -> Start -> Use Start full screen. It is for users who liked Win8 Start sreen

Comment: Doesn’t change my answer.  Your resolution is to blame

Comment: The resolution is HD (1920x1080), pretty standard for business line notebooks. I believe the current screen is just UX flaw, which will be hopefully fixed soon. But your comment reminded me the famous: __It's not bug, it's a feature__ :)